# C unit test: stubbing fread/fwrite functions

Tags: c, unit-testing, stub

I started writing a little program in C as a development excercise and I want to have a lot of unit test for this programs. The problem is that from time to time it uses fread/fwrite and other standard functions - I don't want my unit tests to open any file, so it would be great if I could write stub for fread/fwrite.

Anyone have solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance for answers!

edit: I forgot about one important thing: stub for read need to behave differently in different tests. In one, read return value must be < then passed number of elements to read (simulates too early eof) and in other read return value must be equal to passed number of elements to read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple options:

1. Turn `fopen()`, `fread()`, etc into indirect function calls, through function pointers. For normal operation set them to point to `fopen()`, etc. For testing, set them to point to your functions.
2. Define your replacement functions `myfopen()`, `myfread()`, etc. Compile the main part of the program with the macros named `fopen`, `fread`, etc and expanding into `myfopen`, `myfread`, etc.
3. Define your own `fopen()`, `fread()`, etc. Play with the linker to make them replace the ones from the standard library. This is very error-prone and hard to do.
4. Hook `fopen()`, `fread()`, etc functions using disassembly, assembly and run-time code patching. This isn't easy either.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend the [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://www.amazon.com/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052&ei=OGPuToHVGI2eOpzsqKgD&usg=AFQjCNEq5HkN-DJbjxfJPbXQK0Bl4fbsoQ) book as it deals with this in a number of chapters.  I've used it myself in similar situations.

There's two recommendations for unit testing in procedural languages (other than converting to an object-oriented language):

- Using the "linker seam".  Use wrapper functions around the API calls and compile with different object files depending on whether you're compiling the tests or deliverables.  The test version would stub out the calls inside the wrapper functions, whereas the version for release code would pass the calls through to fread, fwrite, etc.
- Using the "preprocessing seam", where you use #ifdefs to change the behaviour of either fread/fwrite/etc by defining local versions under a test-specific #ifdef or having the slightly more maintainable option of wrapper functions (again) that change behaviour depending on whether the test-specific #ifdef is defined.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the easiest way to do this is to use macro (skipping discussing about its evilness):

```
#ifdef UNIT_TESTS
    #define fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream) (nmemb)
#endif
```

And same for `fread`. Now, you can use compiler flag to specify macro `UNIT_TESTS` when compiling with unit tests (like `gcc -DUNIT_TESTS ...` for gcc).

Comment: Which will cause the programs that actually *check* the return value to fail. .... Next!.

Comment: Don't see any problem here, just `#define fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream) ((nmemb) * (size))`

Comment: Even more wrong. fread() /fwrite() return the number of *items*, not the number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the macro too.

Create a file with:

```
#define fopen FOPEN
#define fread FREAD
#define fwrite FWRITE
```

and then add that as a forced include so it gets in before all other includes.

You can then implement FOPEN in you stub code to do whatever you want.